# How to write JUnit Test case

Tags: junit, spring-data-jpa, mockito

I am learning Junit testing on spring boot Application. my account controller method is depend on service class method. For that I used `Mockito`. I tried simple But here I am not getting how to write test case for following method? How I can use mockito.

can any one please help me for writing this test case?

**AccountController**

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/spacestudy/$ {InstituteIdentifier}/admin/account")
    public class AccountController {

        @Autowired
        AccountService accService;  

        @GetMapping("/findAccountData")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Tuple>> populateGridViews(@RequestParam(value="sClientAcctId",required=false) String sClientAcctId,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="sAcctDesc",required=false) String sAcctDesc,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="sInvestigatorName",required=false)String sInvestigatorName,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="sClientDeptId",required=false) String sClientDeptId) throws Exception {
            return  ResponseEntity.ok(accService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc,sInvestigatorName,sClientDeptId));
        }

    }
```

**AccountService**

```
public List<Tuple> populateGridViews(String sClientAcctId, String sAcctDesc, String sInvestigatorName,
        String sClientDeptId)throws Exception{

    QAccount account = QAccount.account;
    QDepartment department = QDepartment.department;
    QAccountCPCMapping accountCPCMapping = QAccountCPCMapping.accountCPCMapping;
    QInvestigator investigator = QInvestigator.investigator;

    JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(em);
    query.select(Projections.bean(Account.class, account.sClientAcctId, account.sAcctDesc, account.sLocation,
            Projections.bean(Department.class, department.sDeptName, department.sClientDeptId).as("department"),
            Projections.bean(Investigator.class, investigator.sInvestigatorName).as("investigator"),
            Projections.bean(AccountCPCMapping.class, accountCPCMapping.sCCPCode).as("accountCPC"))).from(account)
            .innerJoin(account.department, department).innerJoin(account.accountCPC, accountCPCMapping)
            .innerJoin(account.investigator, investigator);

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sClientAcctId)) {
        query.where(account.sClientAcctId.equalsIgnoreCase(sClientAcctId));
    }
  // code.......


    return query.fetch();       

}
```

**AccountControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestAccountController {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private AccountService accountService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AccountController accountController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
    }

@Test
    public void populateGridViewsTest() throws Exception {

   //????
   //????

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestAccountController {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private AccountService accountService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AccountController accountController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void populateGridViewsTest() throws Exception {
        when(accountService.populateGridViews("foo","bar")).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(new Tuple("bazz"));
        mockMvc.perform(get("/spacestudy/STACKOVERFLOW/admin/account/foo/bar"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("someField").value("bazz"));

    }
}
```

So basically you are replacing your service with mock and saying what it should return. In your particular case I don't see any reasons for unit testing this class, since it doesn't have any logic inside. But if you would have something like:

```
     @GetMapping("/findAccountData")
     public ResponseEntity<List<Tuple>> populateGridViews(...) throws Exception {
       List<Tuple> result = accService.populateGridViews(...);
       if(result==null){
         return ResponseEntity.notFound();
       }
       return  ResponseEntity.ok(result);
     }
```

Then it would make more sense to test this class e.g.

1st test - mock your `accService` to return `null` and verify that response status is 404

2nd test - mock your `accService` to return not `null` and verify that response status is 200